# Access Safari and Chrome cookies for associated domains in iOS app

Tags: ios, cookies, associated-domains

I have website hosted on domain that is associated with iOS mobile app.
Inside mobile app I want to access cookies from this website, which are stored in Chrome and Safari browsers on iPhone.

Is it even possible? And how it can be done?

If I can’t do it, maybe there is some official way of solving task of accessing some website data from app like *webcredentials*?